# How to remove duplicate rows using awk while splitting file

Tags: shell, awk

I'm using awk in a shell script so I can split a file according to the 5th column. The code below is similar to the one I'm using:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1{h=$0; next}
!seen[$5]++{f="FILE_"$5".txt";print h > f} 
{print >> f}' input.txt
```

After generating each file, though, I need to remove duplicate rows. How can I do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input and desired output. That will help us understand what you are doing and how it is failing as well as what you require.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `!seen[$0]++` as test.

you code will be

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1{h=$0; next}
!seen[$0]++{f="FILE_"$5".txt";print h > f} 
{print >> f}' input.txt
```